# Old() com array - Laravel

Tags: laravel

Boas, estou a tentar recuperar o valor com o old() mas não consigo devido à variável $i. Tenho um input como este:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
 <input type="text" name="tempos[]" 
 value="{{old('tempos'.$i,$valores[$i]->minutos)}}"/>
@endfor
```

Obrigado

Comment: Não seria `old('tempos.'.$i)`, com o ponto após `tempos`?

Comment: Experimentei assim e funcionou. Obrigado